# VSTS/DevOps BizTalk automatic deployment to multiple servers in BizTalk Group (BizTalk Server Application Deployment)

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk, continuous-deployment

We are thinking of moving from BTDF to the new VSTS automatic deployment mechanism.

In my test setup, deploying to a single node BTS server worked just fine, but I wonder how it is done having a BizTalk group with multiple servers.
In BTDF the .msi's needed to be run on all nodes (once with 'this is the first server in the group' checked) in order to once create the application and on the other nodes to just install and GAC resources...

Is this being done automatically by the 'Deploy BizTalk Server Application' deployment task or do I have to run it once with 'Create new BizTalk Server application' and on the other servers with 'Install BizTalk Server Application' set?

If yes, do I simply run it on the deployment agent of the node with the management db or would I deploy to a deployment group/environment resource group containing all nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to run the task with "Deploy..." to import and install GAC on a primary server (anyone of your servers). This deployment will create a share with the full MSI.Then, run the deploy task with "Install..." to install only GAC on the secondary servers. I have setted up a CI-CD pipeline and below what i created(farme of 3 servers):

1. Create deployment group with 3 servers(one agent/server)
2. Create a tag on a server primary
3. Create a tag on secondary servers to be
   tagged secondary
4. In the pipeline , you add 2 jobs: one to run only
   on primary server, filtering on the primary capability. and the
   second to filter only the secondary ones.
5. On the first job, the
   deploy task will run to import to biztalk db and run msi, the second
   will only run msi on secondaries

Comment: Was always wondering, what the difference between these two was. Documentation is not quite extensive... Thanks!

Comment: I agree the doc is so general. Please mark as an answer

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have already visited Microsoft's documentation page [Configure automatic deployment with Visual Studio Team Services in BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configure-automatic-deployment-with-visual-studio-team-services-in-biztalk). Please see [Provision deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) to create a deployment group of multiple servers(this is part of the 'Step 2'). Once the Deployment groups are created please make use of them in the 'Release' Phase of the CICD pipeline as shown in this GIF image [Release Pipeline BTS Deploy Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAXBg.gif)

[Get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configure-automatic-deployment-with-visual-studio-team-services-in-biztalk#get-started)

Step 1: Add Application project & update .json template

Step 2: Create the VSTS token & install the build agent

Step 3: Create the build and release definitions

Comment: Thanks, but not really answering the question.